# Use Http Proxy in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http

I live in a restricted country & Services like Firebase need VPN to be used.
so I'm creating the flutter application which uses Firebase as a backend & i want to know can i set Proxy to whole of the connections in app to GET & POST, etc. requests ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said for what platform, but at least for Unix-like things, most applications and libraries respect the `http_proxy` environment variable, which you can set in most shells like:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://server-ip:port/
$ export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
$ export http_proxy=http://proxy-server.mycorp.com:3128/
$ export http_proxy=http://foo:bar@server-ip:port/
$ export http_proxy=http://foo:bar@127.0.0.1:3128/
$ export http_proxy=http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@proxy-server.mycorp.com:3128/
```

The proper string will be specific to your environment.  Details on interpretation of the environment variables are at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient/findProxyFromEnvironment.html.

Answer (score 4):

1. For windows By setting in Environment Variables ( System Properties )

> ```
> http_proxy=http://server_ip:port
>
> https_proxy=http://server_ip:port
> ```

2. pub_specs.yaml

   http_proxy: ^1.1.0
3. main.dart

> ```
> import 'package:http_proxy/http_proxy.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
>
> ...
>
>
> void main() async {
>
>   ...
>
>   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
>   HttpProxy httpProxy = await HttpProxy.createHttpProxy();
>   httpProxy.host = "server_ip";// replace with your server ip
>   httpProxy.port = "port";// replace with your server port
>   HttpOverrides.global=httpProxy;
>
>   ...
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use this package to fix the issue: https://github.com/kaivean/system_proxy. Specifically this allows you to retrieve the system level proxy info and then apply it to your HTTP client.

The guide in the README worked great. The rest of this answer is just taken from that:

Import

```
import 'package:system_proxy/system_proxy.dart';
```

Code

```
// the proxy value likes:  {port: 8899, host: 127.0.0.1}
Map<String, String>? proxy = await SystemProxy.getProxySettings();
if (proxy != null) {
    print('proxy $proxy');
}
```

Setting Proxy for HttpClient

```
class ProxiedHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  ProxiedHttpOverrides(this._host, this._port);

  String _port;
  String _host;

  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      // set proxy
      ..findProxy = (uri) {
        return _host != null ? "PROXY $_host:$_port;" : 'DIRECT';
      };
  }
}

void main() async {
  Map<String, String>? proxy = await SystemProxy.getProxySettings();
  if (proxy == null) {
    proxy = {
    'host': null,
    'port': null
    };
  }
  HttpOverrides.global = new ProxiedHttpOverrides(proxy['host'], proxy['port']);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```